# Automating TFS tasks using Powershell when TFS client is on non-domain machine

Tags: windows, powershell, tfs

I am doing a build automation where build client is on a non domain machine. It is not possible to move this machine to domain. TFS server is version 2013 and connection to it works via Visual studio 2013. Credentials also get saved in windows vault in Windows server 2012.

When I use TF.exe from developer command prompt, it is able to take the parameters '/login:username,[password]' and work.

This parameter do not work with TFS powertool TFPT though. TFPT always asks for login and password via UI prompt even though the same is saved in Windows Vault also.

Same is the case with TFPT powershell cmdlet also.

Is this expected behavior? Should I continue with TF.exe use or are there alternatives?

**[UPDATE]** 
As per [an answer on MSDN forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2c0c482b-36bd-4832-8c00-e26a23049c86/automating-tfs-tasks-using-powershell-when-tfs-client-is-on-nondomain-machine?forum=tfsgeneral), it is not possible to provide /login parameter to TFPT. Using a shadow account or TF.exe is the way out. TF.exe worked out for me once I started digging.

Comment: Which TFPT.exe command did you run?

Comment: I have tried few commands including `tfpt query` and `tfpt scorch` and all asks for credentials.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `tfpt connections` command to modify Team Explorer client connection values.

If you want to use `tfpt online` command, try `tfpt online /preview /recursive /noprompt`, which will prevent the system from prompting the user for any information.

Comment: I have tried the '/noprompt' option and it does not stop the UI from coming. `tfpt online` is not valid for local workspaces and thus not useful for me. `tfpt connections` shows the list of credentials saved in the system but other tfpt commands fails to use that.

Comment: You can try to create a shadow account to make cross domain communication. Check https://blogs.blackmarble.co.uk/blogs/rfennell/post/2012/07/20/Getting-TFS-2012-Agents-to-communicate-cross-domain.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I can get the credential saved in Windows Vault works with PowerShell. Steps for your reference:

1. Open tfs web portal from IE: http://xxxxx:8080/tfs
2. Enter the username and password and check "Remember my credentials" option.
3. Click "OK" button.

The credential is saved in Windows Vault now and no dialog will prompt when I run tfpt command from PowerShell. My PC hasn't joined in the domain either.